# IE draws svg backwards on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, svg, scroll

I've been working on a scroll and draw svg path using JQuery and js, like in this pen by Ben Laley: http://codepen.io/paintbycode/pen/JDbcF

It works on Chrome and Firefox but IE seems to be playing my animation backwards, and I can't figure out why.

I'm using the same js code as in that codepen example, and also using JQuery. 
(I am extremely new to js, apologies for incorrectly formatted code)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $dashOffset = $(".all").css("stroke-dashoffset");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var $percentageComplete = (($(window).scrollTop() / ($("html").height()     - 

$(window).height())) * 100);
    var $newUnit = parseInt($dashOffset, 10);
    var $offsetUnit = $percentageComplete * ($newUnit / 100);
    $(".all").css("stroke-dashoffset", $newUnit - $offsetUnit);
  });
});
```

Comment: 11, though tried on 10 as well

Comment: Been developing in up to date versions of Chrome and Firefox, and the js is embedded in the html file, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the popular scrolling stroke in svg.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("woman");

var path = svg.getElementsByTagName('path');

function scrollOn(percentage) {
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    var length = path[i].getTotalLength();
    var amount = length * percentage;
    //console.log(amount);
    path[i].setAttribute("style", "stroke-dashoffset:" + amount + "; stroke-dasharray: " + length + ";");
  }
}

var viewportHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height()
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
  var percentage = 1 - (scrollAmount / viewportHeight)
  scrollOn(percentage);
});
```

```css
.fil1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5;
}
#woman {
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
}

body {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="woman" viewBox="0 0 1000 1500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="fil1" d="M103.108 748.113c-8.40381,-12.7029 -28.2643,-26.1248 -26.1814,-41.2129 8.13333,-58.8938 178.847,-152.415 205.09,-169.696 70.2671,-46.2705 40.3852,-144.601 58.181,-200.727 24.5786,-77.5224 50.0181,-158.041 98.9086,-223.029 33.7371,-44.8462 67.1071,-88.26 141.091,-88.7271 33.7567,-0.212381 81.091,12.4281 113.453,35.8786 16.6367,12.0548 12.1338,30.731 16,50.909 2.98905,15.6052 13.3133,18.1019 14.5424,35.1967 0.741905,10.3257 4.96667,24.4329 3.8981,38.1914 -1.03286,13.3062 -6.91048,27.019 -4.37952,35.9448 4.5319,15.979 30.7724,29.0124 30.061,46.3033 -0.711905,17.2905 -17.2019,10.1952 -19.1524,18.181 -1.95048,7.98619 8.02238,9.89048 7.51524,16.0005 -0.266667,3.21952 -6.77095,4.76905 -8,7.75667 -1.3581,3.3 4.42095,7.86714 3.87905,11.3943 -0.775714,5.05 -7.35476,7.51762 -8.96952,12.3638 -4.2,12.6043 0.108571,30.3852 -10.1824,38.7886 -12.0281,9.82286 -30.381,6.52714 -46.0595,6.30238 -5.25952,-0.0747619 -15.5824,-2.62048 -18.9095,1.45429 -14.5395,17.8029 -20.9457,38.7152 -27.1505,60.8486 -3.84762,13.7248 -3.72238,29.3843 1.45429,42.6662 2.93381,7.5281 15.8224,7.29762 19.3933,14.5457 29.8276,60.5338 50.8371,125.094 79.5148,186.181 5.78476,12.3224 14.639,23.271 22.6676,34.5186 7.43619,10.419 14.1662,21.0952 17.09,33.3605 4.56,19.1238 -2.79333,39.7719 -9.69667,58.1814 -5.03952,13.4395 -21.1267,21.1495 -25.2124,34.9086 -12.0571,40.6024 -14.371,83.4862 -22.3029,125.091 -7.90619,41.471 -25.5376,81.9043 -25.2119,124.12 0.334286,43.2981 15.6948,85.2738 27.1514,127.03 3.17476,11.5705 12.3376,20.7419 16.4843,32 2.7181,7.3781 -1.03429,19.1214 2.42476,26.1819 5,10.2024 14.7752,24.6562 21.7267,36.5324 4.14905,7.08857 5.4219,12.6376 9.25476,17.5405 6.4519,8.25333 10.59,6.00333 15.0786,15.7448 3.65333,7.93048 -1.47524,17.7995 0.97,26.1819 3.49714,11.9867 23.6376,35.7524 11.1514,35.5781 -149.416,-2.09476 -297.22,-1.85905 -451.392,-1.93905 -4.21619,-0.00190476 -9.87619,-20.1152 -13.0086,-28.97 -3.17238,-8.96952 -10.0871,-10.1467 -14.0152,-19.5205 -62.9857,-150.3 31.38,-241.583 83.2667,-304.178 7.16429,-8.6419 -37.9162,-47.3733 -60.121,-67.879 -41.319,-38.1567 -93.411,-64.8714 -129.939,-107.636 -44.5567,-52.1638 -62.3748,-74.9438 -100.363,-132.363z"
  />
  <path class="fil1" d="M234.636 719.623c3.54524,-11.3395 70.4267,-34.7195 104.242,-61.091 11.1338,-8.68238 7.93762,27.1024 11.6367,40.7271 2.44286,9.00286 -0.248095,33.2443 2.42381,42.181 1.26762,4.23857 7.29714,-10.8205 10.0024,-8.45286 3.66952,3.21238 4.48524,23.4262 9.3919,26.8786 11.6657,8.20952 28.3729,-7.45524 36.3633,4.36238 5.33381,7.8881 2.93571,23.2033 5.98286,32.1105 7.43143,21.721 16.0786,38.9238 21.6533,61.4652 3.46333,14.0033 5.97381,28.299 7.27286,42.6671 1.61619,17.8724 8.75476,37.4252 1.45381,53.8181 -1.65143,3.70714 -7.5619,1.89905 -12.1624,2.65762 -5.75857,0.949524 -10.5681,3.72667 -14.9881,1.22048 -20.7871,-11.7871 -36.3157,-31.2629 -52.3638,-48.969 -23.1533,-25.5457 -43.2495,-54.1957 -64.97,-80.9695 -6.88571,-8.4881 -26.371,-42.7038 -44.8829,-72.8548 -10.9781,-17.8795 -22.2819,-31.829 -21.0557,-35.751z"
  />
  <path class="fil1" d="M634.633 1261.68c2.76095,-12.1281 6.92,-42.9319 15.5152,-33.94 15.8452,16.5757 21.091,44.5505 15.9995,66.909 -2.40762,10.5767 -19.6557,-10.0981 -27.1505,-17.939 -3.60524,-3.77048 -5.52238,-9.94381 -4.36429,-15.03z" />
  <path class="fil1" d="M455.727 130.53c-24.5652,16.4852 -58.3595,35.201 -73.6967,49.4548 -22.2171,20.6476 -12.6557,44.5881 -6.30286,69.3333l4.36429 6.30286" />
</svg>
```

How its done. 
We animate the `stroke-dasharray` property.

The long explanation:

1. Find the height of our window: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
2. Find out current scroll: $(window).scrollTop();
3. add it to a scroll event: $(document).scroll([...])
4. add a percentage (0 to 1): (scrollAmount / viewportHeight)
5. use this percentage to draw a path-offset: se scrollOn()
6. add the calculated stroke-dashoffset with to its style

Comment: @technicolor could you upvote it and accept it if it answered your question?

Comment: I will do so, I haven't had a chance to go through it and test yet, but as soon as I verify it's the correct answer, I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this code fixes the problem:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $dashOffset = $(".all").css("stroke-dashoffset");
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    var $percentageComplete = (($(window).scrollTop() / 
($(document).height() + $(window).height())) * 100);
    var $newUnit = parseInt($dashOffset, 10);
    var $offsetUnit = $percentageComplete * ($newUnit / 100);
    $(".all").css("stroke-dashoffset", $newUnit - $offsetUnit);
  });
});
</script>
```

Basically, this line:

```
var $percentageComplete = (($(window).scrollTop() / ($("html").height() -
$(window).height())) * 100);
```

was replaced with:

```
var $percentageComplete = (($(window).scrollTop() / 
($(document).height() + $(window).height())) * 100);
```

I hope this makes sense to you guys, I'm still muddling through what's going on.